# how to Validate captcha before submit a form in joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla-3.6, validation, captcha

I have installed 5 captcha plugins in my joomla site and i set any one captcha out of 5 in `com_users` configuration in backend of joomla.

So how can I want to validate that captcha from client browser in registration form, **client side validation for every captcha from client browser**?

Comment: Have you read the documentation at https://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_use_Recaptcha_in_Joomla%3F ?

Comment: This question has also been posted at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39372617/1983389

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Google's reCaptcha that is the default plugin for Joomla!, the validation is done off site and a pass or fail "flag" is returned to your form...no further action needed from you.